# Callback function comprehension and return statement

Tags: javascript

Don't understand why I have to make the assignment on line 28 to make the code work! Lines 17 to 21 is where I get the results.This is a very basic solution - more interested in why the code works.

//Given a list of non-negative integers and a target sum, find a pair of numbers  that sums to the target sum.

```
function findPairForSum(integers, target) 
{
  // your solution here
  var integerPairArray = [];
  // first have the first element as one of the pairs
  var firstInteger = integers[0];
  // will store the sum of integers
  var sum = 0;
    // iterate through the remaining elements
  for(var index = 1; index < integers.length; index++)
  {
   // add each to the first element and compare the result with the target
    sum = firstInteger + integers[index];
      // if true then return the pair in an array
   if(sum === target)
   {
     integerPairArray.push(firstInteger, integers[index]);
     break;
   }
   // if the end of the array is reached and there is no result
   if(index === integers.length - 1 && sum !== target)
   {
     // remove the first element from the array
     integers.shift();
      // repeat the loop
     integerPairArray = findPairForSum(integers, target);
   }   
  }
  return integerPairArray;
}

// example
var pair = findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 17);
console.log(pair); // --> [12, 5]
```

Comment: you need to return the final result back to your original call from outside the function on the second last line. When you call the function within the function it will return the result back to the function if there is nothing to catch that result and return it back to the second last line then you didn't do much of anything by recurring the function. This is for sure a homework assignment though lol.

Comment: Short answer is without that `return` then `pair` would be undefined

Comment: Thanks @Solomon P Byer - appreciate your help!

Comment: And you too @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has comments, and no answers, I will endeavor to provide an answer based on the comments made .@Solomon P Byer really helped me understand my code! Thank you!
The final return statement from the `findPairForSum(integers, target)` declaration will go to this function call/expression - `var pair = findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 17);` - made outside the function.

Because I made a recursive call within the `findPairForSum(integers, target)` function, the final `return` statement will initially go to the call within the function. And because it is a `return` statement, it has to be ‘caught’ as @Solomon P Byer mentioned.

It is caught by the `integerPairArray` variable and then the final `return` statement in the function returns the answer to the function call made outside the function and we get the answer! Whew!